# Can't use INDIRECT in a named range used by an Excel chart

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am setting up several charts that are designed to dynamically select the last  rows in a data set, or the number of available rows, if that's smaller.  I have that set up and working, but I want all of the charts to use a (dynamically sized) range for the category axis values as well, and I'm running into trouble with that.

If I have categories in column A and values in column B, and a named value 'chtLen, then, say 'values' is a dynamically named range defined by `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$1,COUNT(Sheet1!$B:$B),0,-MIN(chtLen,COUNT(Sheet1!$B:$B)),1)`

Then it's simple to create a 'categories' value as `=OFFSET(values,0,-1)`

An Excel chart will accept `=Book1.xlsx!categories` as the range for the category axis values, and everything works. But if I want to *always* use column A, and grab a range in that column, that is, I want to change 'categories to `=OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MIN(ROW(Book1.xlsx!values)),1)),0,0,COUNT(Book1.xlsx!values),1)`

While still in the named value editor, both of those options will correctly select the same range.  But when I try to change 'categories' to the latter formula, the category axis disappears from the chart.  Attempting to edit or add `=Book1.xlsx!categories` to the chart with that definition results in 'Excel found a problem ... check that cell references, range names, defined names and links to other workbooks in your formulas are correct'.

The only thing I *think* I am changing is how I am arriving at a range.  What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome!  It would be helpful if you could include a sample of the data you're talking about.  Also, check out the [tour] (you'll earn your first badge!) as well as "[ask]" and more tips in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: You have a couple "minus signs" in there which is likely giving the range a **negative height**.  The [**documentation for `OFFSET`**](https://support.office.com/article/offset-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66) confirms that height needs to be a **positive number.**

Comment: You could break down the formulas into smaller sections to make sure each part is functioning properly.  For example, what does `ROW(Book1.xlsx!values)` return? What about `MIN(ROW(Book1.xlsx!values))`? And `ADDRESS(MIN(ROW(Book1.xlsx!values)),1)`? ... `-MIN(chtLen,COUNT(Sheet1!$B:$B))`?  Not sure why you are using `INDIRECT`.

Comment: Hi, @ashleedawg! I would love to include sample data, but can't figure out how to attach a file.  I have a sample file with both the working and non-working ranges.   The one with the negative height works; it's the one with a positive height that isn't, although, again, when in the name editor, it is showing the correct range.  I tried the components separately, and got the correct value that I want to pass to indirect.  I want to use indirect because address gives you a text value of a cell location, and offset requires an actual reference.  Is there a better formula to use than indirect?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to make sure I shared the solution I got to work.  Instead of relying on the ADDRESS/INDIRECT functions, I just did simple algebra.  It's ugle, and includes off-by-one errors that have to be corrected, but this works, regardless of the length of the data set:

```
=offset($A$1, ROW(values)+ROWS(values)-2, 0, -ROWS(values), 1)
```

That is, if I know I always want to draw my category values from column A, this will figure out how many rows down from the top of the category column my last data point is, and offset down that far, then offset 0 rows, then make the length the same length as the data set, going back up, and the result is one column wide.  Not pretty but it works.